# How to access fields inside a stream resource in PHP?

Tags: php, stream

I cannot access individual fields inside a stream resource (called `$handle`).

The resource is a result of me checking if an image file exists on the server:

```
$handle = @fopen($cdnPath . "/adblock" . $site_id . '.jpg', 'r');
```

If it does, I get this when id execute dump($handle);

```
stream resource @97 ▼
  crypto: array:4 [▶]
  timed_out: false
  blocked: true
  eof: false
  wrapper_data: array:17 [▶]
  wrapper_type: "http"
  stream_type: "tcp_socket/ssl"
  mode: "r"
  unread_bytes: 552
  seekable: false
  uri: "https://cdn.pixfuture.com/adblock_logo/adblock14.jpg"
  options: []
}
```

How can I access the `uri` field, and store it into a variable?
I tried `$handle->uri`, and `$handle['uri']`, none of which worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `stream_get_meta_data`. [Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-meta-data.php).

```php
$f    = fopen($uri, 'r');
$meta = stream_get_meta_data($f);

echo $meta['uri'];
```